# One word for "take into consideration"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Is there one word for "take into consideration". I searched online, but didn't find any. For example,

> We also have to take into consideration the fact that the 
>       requirements might change later on.

Comment: [consider](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/consider) comes to mind

Comment: There's the common slang _tic_ for offences _taken into consideration_, but I doubt that's quite what you had in mind (you want a verb, and aren't up in front of the magistrates).

Comment: I'm not a native speaker, but maybe "mind the fact" would also fit. Or "allow for possible changes in the requirements later on"

Comment: Your exemplar is excessively wordy, IMO.  Being in favor of succinctness, I suggest the following:  "We must consider future requirement changes" (six words versus 16).

Comment: I hate the fact that there are many supercilious people on this forum who simply just have to downvote every question. Other forums on stackexchange have less arrogant people. Just because you're good at English, it doesn't mean you're better than others.

Comment: If you hover over the downvote button it says "This question does not show any research effort". I suspect that is why people downvoted. You say you searched online. What did you find and why was it not suitable? That would avoid others suggesting the same thing and might help to guide towards what might be suitable. Also, have you tried a dictionary or thesaurus, and, if so, why are its suggestions not suitable?

Comment: @TrevorD that would be more like "I was looking for an elephant, but I found a zebra, a tiger, a leopard, a rhino... but obviously they're not an elephant." I don't see the point of always mentioning what I found and why it wasn't a match.

Comment: Then don't complain if others think differently, especially given the guidance [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): "Try a dictionary ... Try a thesaurus *if you want to know words or phrases that have a similar meaning to one you already know.* ... *Be sure to mention the research you've done and what you're still hoping to learn!*"

Comment: Do you agree with mplungjan's suggestion, *consider*? If not, why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Besides *[consider](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/consider#Verb)* (“To think about seriously”),  *[weigh](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/weigh#Verb)* (“To consider a subject”) may serve.  For example: “We must weigh the likelihood that requirements might change later.”

Answer (score 2):

Regard.

We also have to **regard** the fact that the requirements might change later on.

Answer (score 1):

I like Deliberate

Verb:
Engage in long and careful consideration: "she deliberated over the menu".

Comment: Using the Op's sentence, you can't say "We also have to ***deliberate*** the fact that the requirements might change later on."

Comment: Op's sentence is an example and not the point of the question.

Comment: But OP's request is for "take into consideration", which implies an *additional* issue to consider, which is not covered by "deliberate". You might deliberate over the menu, but still have to *take into consideration* that someone won't eat meat. "Deliberate" does *not* cover that. Also, as per the Help & other site info, please cite the source of your reference.

Comment: The word consider is in the very definition of deliberate. So I'm afraid it covers it very much. It is, at least, as good an answer as "consider" or "weigh" or "ponder". I didn't notice anyone else citing sources... anything else?

Answer (score 1):

How about *ponder*:

> Verb
>
> Think about (something) carefully, esp. before deciding or concluding